# Coupling of objects

Tags: design-patterns, coupling, cohesion

Assuming I have methods of doA(), doB() and doC() of classes A,B and C respectively.

Than unless I am wrong, doA() method should belong to class A. It must be executed from Class A. If a method doA() that does the responsibilities for A, exists in Class B. than class A is coupled to B's services. This also represents low cohesion, and high coupling

is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Tell us more; what does doA() actually do in relation to the A class?  Does it create an A or consume an A or update an A or what?

Comment: Class A is the information expert. It is a Board object. doA() represents the getSquare() method. and Class B represents the Square object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class has **maximum cohesion** if all its methods operate on all it's member variables.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int value1;
    private int value2;
    private int value3;

    public int Method1()
    {
        return value1 + value2;
    }

    public int Method2()
    {
        return value1 - value2;
    }

    // doesn't belong on this class
    public int Method3()
    {
        return value3 * 2;
    }
}
```

Coupling comes in two forms:

1. A class uses another class internally. This is coupling but is kind of okay in that it's an example of composition over inheritance

Example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void Method1()
    {
        var c = new MyOtherClass();
        c.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

1. Worse coupling looks like this and is often referred to as a [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) violation.

Example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void Method1()
    {
        var c = new MyOtherClass();
        var size = c.Members.Size;
        ...
    }
}
```

In this case, `MyClass` is coupled not only to `MyOtherClass`, but the *structure* of `MyOtherClass` and this is where you get into trouble and your code gets rigid and fragile.